# Animated gif does not animate on page load in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a resource intensive ASP.NET page. I have a `div` element with an image that I set the visibility for before and the after the page loads. This fails in IE. IE stops animating the image.

I have tried all possible solutions that were presented in different message boards with no luck.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: can you post the relevant code setup that you have at the moment? Are you referring to full postbacks, async postbacks, ajax requests or a combination?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your are using an UpdatePanel and IE is pegged trying to parse the DOM.  See this article for [KB 2000262 - Fix: UpdatePanel Async Postbacks Slow in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000262).  Check your task manager when this happens and see if IExplore.exe is %100.